# Joint distribution of two random variables conditionally to a given $x$

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose that ($X$, $Y$ and $Z$) are three random variables with joint pdf
\begin{align}
f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\pi}\exp(x(y+z-x-2))-\frac{1}{2}(y^2+x^2), & x\geq 0,\; x\in R, \; y\in R \\
0, & \text{oterwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Ι have to find the joint conditional distribution of $Y$ and $Z$, given $X=x$.

My problem is that I can't solve the integral above.
\begin{align}
F(z,y|X=x)=\int_{0}^{y} \int_{0}^{z} \frac{1}{\pi}\exp(x(k+t-x-2))-\frac{1}{2}(k^2+t^2)\,\mathrm{d}k\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If $x$ is fixed and $g(y,z):=f(x,y,z)$ then $g(y,z)$ is "almost" a PDF of the conditional distribution that you mention. It only fails when it comes to the condition $\int\int g(y,z)dydz=1$, but this can be repaired by dividing $g(y,z)$ by the constant $\int\int g(y,z)dydz$. It is not necessary to find the conditional CDF as you yield.

Answer (score 0):

$$f_{Y,Z}(y,z|X=x) = \frac{f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)}{f_{X}(x)}$$

Find the marginal $f_{X}(x) = \int_{y}\int_{z}f_{X,Y,X}(x,y,z)dzdy$ and divide joint pdf by it.